# android studio new project cannot find symbol 'R'

Tags: android, android-studio

I just made a clean android studio project and I'm getting errors in my Main file saying R isn't found. I know it's not an xml error since it's a new project...I've tried to sync project with gradle files but that doesn't seem to do anything. It just comes back with an :app:mergeDebugResources error..

Comment: MainActivity.Java....the standard. I said it was a clean/fresh project creation.

Answer (score 6):

Select `Build` > `Clean Project`

It should rebuild and recreate the R file :-)

Comment: I only wish it were that simple, haha :(

Comment: Figured it out. I was having an issue with ubuntu and opening aapt files. fixed! :)

Comment: Well you got dis likes -_- , that's what i hate here , people instead of helping (when they cannot help but they still conceive them as Programming
 God, being frustrated and answerless) they dislike ;)
I also asked a valid WLS Oracle question and got a dislike and no one replied with answer ;)