# "Cannot find symbol R" error after renaming package name

Tags: android

After renaming my project package name (with Refactor), I got this error:

```
Error:(7, 44) error: cannot find symbol class R
```

All of my `R` usages are invalid. I tried to fix it manually but it doesn't work for me. `Invalidate chases/Restart` doesn't help me, either.

Comment: remove `import android.R;`  if there is

Comment: R is an automatically generated file. Clean the project by ./gradlew clean or clean in Android studio. Compiling the project again will generate those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio new project cannot find symbol 'R'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440577/android-studio-new-project-cannot-find-symbol-r)

Comment: @Fundhor this soution doesn't work for me(

Comment: did you update the applicationId to your new package name  in build.gradle

Comment: In addition I say that after refactor all packcages and AndroidManifext.xml, File -> invalidate caches/restart, Work for me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try the following :

> Try deleting your R.java file , android studio will regenerate it.
>
> Clean Project
>
> Rebuild Project

And check:

> Check the AndroidManifest.xml, there's a package attribute on the  top-level element

(Well it depends on how you renamed your package name)

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml had the old package name, thanks!

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml`  had the old package name for me too!

Comment: For me Android Studio deleted a part of the package name after renaming!

Comment: For me AndroidManifest.xml somehow didn't have any package attribute at all so apparently that can happen too

Comment: check value `namespace` in `build.gradle` also

Answer (score 8):

Just do the following:

Ensure that the package name at the header of the AndroidManifest file has been renamed to your new package name. This worked for me.

Comment: This. When you refactor the package name to "com.X.Y", the package name in the header of AndroidManifest gets changed to "X.Y". You just have to add "com." at the beginning to resolve all the errors

Answer (score 8):

When all these answers do not work:

In Android Studio : Menu File -> Invalidate Caches and restart Android Studio

Comment: after refactoring minmap & icon file because of uppercase, it wouldn't bring correct name and always had an error, with this it finally undrestood

Comment: I tried many of the suggested ways but THIS WAY worked for me. I had no references, anywhere to my old package name and when Android Studio wanted to import the "R" class, it always referred to my previous package name, which then obviously did not physically exist so could not be imported. Clearing the caches then re indexes atc from scratch and then all works fine. I personally would try THIS METHOD first.

Answer (score 5):

Try to change application Id in build.gradle.
Or remove any imports of com.***.R in your activity and let android studio to automatically import for you.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like, you changed the application package name but didn't change the import statements. So look for import statement of class R. It must be like

```
import <package_name>.R;
```

If it's not a problem with import statements then look whether the R.java file has generated or not. It generally doesn't get generated if there is a problem with the application layout(xml) files. The R class file is generated only when all your xml layout files are correct.

Clean the project and check.

Answer (score 4):

[image: R error after renaming pakage]

3 packages you may see as marked, When you edit the package name make sure you change all 3 of them else you may face R error which will prompt you to press alt+enter to name it as ur old package name

Answer (score 4):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml ( com.package1.package2 )

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.package1.package2">
```

90% of symbol R errors because of that line.
When you refactor your old package, mostly cases this package didn't change

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this error showed because I changed the package name without ticking the boxes (*Search in comments and strings*   and  *Search for text occurrences*)

[image]

**The solution for me:**
Rename package again and make sure you **tick** the two boxes as in the photo, then **Do Refactor**

Answer (score 1):

if you rename your android manifest package you have to rename the "packages com.newname" sentence at the beginning of your class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first close android studio. Then

1. Delete "build" folder
2. open the commandline and type `gradlew clean`
3. Then type `gradlew assembledebug`
4. If the build succeeds, feel free to go back to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also rename the `namespace` in the build.gradle (app level) file.
Looks like this namespace is separate from the package directories. So while using refactoring to rename a package directory will change all the imports, it will actually not change the namespace which the "R" import depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Also try clicking "Sync Project With Gradle Files" in the toolbar on the top right of Android Studio. It's the little elephant (looks like a brontosaurus though) with the arrow. I had to do that even after cleaning and rebuilding the project before the problems went away.