# cannot find symbol class R android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-resources

cannot find symbol class R

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol R after renaming package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826801/cannot-find-symbol-r-after-renaming-package-name)

Comment: Please add your gradle files to your question. Not only the error and an image

Comment: @ADM It's only been an hour

Comment: Yeah i mentioned it because question seems with incomplete details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported `import <package_name>.R;` (you can use *Alt + Enter*), than **clean** and **rebuild** your project (*Build* → *Clean Project* / *Rebuild Project*)
Note: Sometimes importing R file could not resolve the issue

Comment: If you look at the question, it's not the local package's R being resolved

Comment: @cricket_007 I wrote it when no much information was provided in the question (screen was uploaded later)

Comment: Sure, but the image was there. The question was formatted wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the project xml design contains any error. in that case R file could not be created. So please verify the xml file if no such error found then rebuild the project  using Build → Clean Project / Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there are any errors in your build.gradle (Module: app) file, and then sync it by using the refresh button from the Gradle panel.
2. Build > Clean Project, and then Build > Rebuild Project

I have been using MacBook Pro for my Android development, but I don't shut down but use the sleep mode normally. Because of this, my Android Studio gets out of control occasionally. Therefore, by simply restarting your entire development PC might resolve your issue.

Alternatively, you can try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart to clean up all the related caches.